# Flood Element - get an ElementHandle inside an iframe

Tags: flood-element

My document looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello

        <iframe ...>
            <input name='cardNumber'>
        </iframe>
    </body
</html>
```

I would like to be able to set the input value programmatically. Doing a simple `browser.findElement(By.css("input"))` doesn't work, because the browser blocks it because of the same-origin policy (see the question here for details [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame))

Therefore I am trying some magic, but I can't make it to work:

```
const ccIframe = browser
    .page
    .frames()
    .find(async frame => {
        return await frame.title() === "Secure card number input frame"
    }) as Frame;
```

But now `ccIframe` is of type `Frame` which does not have `findElement` or `sendKeys` methods. I tried using `ccIframe.press` instead, but it does not set the value on my form input:

```
await ccIframe.press("input[name='cardnumber']", "4")
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that there is some buggy behaviour in selecting a frame like this:

```
const ccIframe = browser
    .page
    .frames()
    .find(async frame => {
        return await frame.title() === "Secure card number input frame"
    }) as Frame;
```

Changed the comparison to use `frame.url()` instead, which is `sync` and it fixed frame selection issue.

Now I type into the input element like this:

```
var ccNumber = await ccIframe.$("input[name='cardnumber']")
await ccNumber?.type("4242424242424242", { delay: 40 })
```

Works like charm!